# Get fullscreen camera preview iPhone?

Tags: iphone, camera, fullscreen, preview

By default it gives a 320x426 (instead of 480) camera image.
Any suggestions? Anybody solved *(rescaling is not a really good option)*?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Medium Quality or Hight quality?

```
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
```

Comment: I realized now - http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/archives/2010/07/06/3Dcompass_augmented_reality_085_-_fullscreen_camera_preview/ - that the camera preview's aspect ratio will always remain 3:4, so scaling is the only way to make it fullscreen (with cropping or distort).